# Why is Django sending duplicate error messages after upgrade to v2.2?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, error-handling

After upgrading to `Django 2.2` from version `1.8`, my app began receiving duplicate error messages. Every error, no matter the type, is now sent to my `ADMINS` email twice.

I am running my app on `Heroku` and tried their support, but they determined that it had something to do with my app. I have been unable to find similar issues online or on `stackoverflow`.

**MY LOGGING CONFIGURATION**

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I was able to replicate this on my local server and noticed that the double emails stopped when I changed `'propagate': True,` to `False` in the `loggers` setting. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/logging/#naming-loggers):

> This propagation can be controlled on a per-logger basis. If you don’t want a particular logger to propagate to its parents, you can turn off this behavior.

However, I am still unsure what my best solution should be. I am wary that setting propagate to `False` will not solve the root cause.

Comment: Do you have LOGGING_CONFIG = None? If not, then perhaps you're propagating  to the disabled root logger, and getting a second email.

Comment: Perfect! I added `LOGGING_CONFIG = None` in addition to `import logging.config` at the top of settings and `logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)` after my custom logging configuration, and now no longer receive duplicate messaging. If you create an answer, I will accept - otherwise, I'll write one up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @gregory for the suggestion to include `LOGGING_CONFIG = None` in my settings. According to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/logging/#disabling-logging-configuration):

> This will disable the configuration process for Django’s default logging.

Final working code:

```
import logging.config

LOGGING_CONFIG = None

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}

logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
```